# Checkbox список из many2many связи в Yii2

Tags: yii2, checkbox, activerecord

У меня есть

1. Фото
2. Альбом

Каждое фото может лежать в нескольких альбомах. То есть в окошке создания и редактирования фото у меня должен быть список с чекбоксами доступных мне альбомов. Если фото новое, чекбоксы все сняты. Если фото редактируется, то все альбомы, где есть фото, отмечены чекбоксами. Как это реализовать в Yii2, подскажите, пожалуйста?

P.S. Хочется отдельно отметить, что проблема заключается не в выводе информации, а в ее изменении и валидации

Comment: Нашел, что в Yii2 есть некие динамические модели. Мне кажется, что [это](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368084/activeform-without-model-yii2) может как-то помочь

Comment: Вот так вот можно вывести отмеченный список:
`$form->field($model, 'albums')->checkboxList(
        Album::find()->select('name')->indexBy('id')->column()
    )`
Как его теперь сохранить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение оказалось достаточно простым, но не очевидным:

Вот этот код будет у нас в модели:

```
/** Здесь мы будем хранить IDшники до сохранения*/
private $_albumsId = null;

/** Приколупываем события, чтобы сохранить связи после сохранения модели.*/
public function init()
{
    $this->on(static::EVENT_AFTER_INSERT, [$this, 'saveAlbumsId']);
    $this->on(static::EVENT_AFTER_UPDATE, [$this, 'saveAlbumsId']);

    parent::init();
}

/**
 * Этот метод возвращает нам список idшников всех прилинкованных альбомов
 */
public function setAlbumsId($ids)
{
    $this->_albumsId = (array) $ids;
}

/**
 * Этот метод сохраняет состояние
 */
protected function saveAlbumsId()
{
    //сброс всех текущих связей
    $this->unlinkAll('albums', true);
    $albums = Album::find()->where(['id' => $this->_albumsId])->all();
    foreach ($albums as $album) {
        //Здесь Ваш способ линкования моделей. У меня это делается вот так:
        $this->albums = $album;
    }
}

/**
 * Этот метод возвращает нам список idшников всех прилинкованных альбомов
 */
public function getAlbumsId()
{
    return $this->getRelation('albums')->indexBy('id')->select('id')->column();
}


/**
 * Обязательно делаем свойство безопасным.
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['albumsId'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
```

Вот такой код у нас будет в форме:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'albumsId')->label('Альбомы')->checkboxList(
    Albums::find()->select('name')->indexBy('id')->column()
) ?>
```

Итого, все обрабатывается как нужно. В контроллере ничего дописывать не нужно, все замечательно подгружается методом load

Comment: спасибо за getRelation(). А то я свою функцию написал уже)

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас есть общая таблица(раз many-to-many то), где лежат Id фотографий и Id альбомов и прописана связь  между моделью Фото и этой общей таблицей. (Я всё генерировал через CRUD Gii)

Что-то типа такого в модели Photo:

```
public function getPhotoAlbums()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PhotoAlbums::className(), ['photo_id' => 'photo_id']);
}
public function getAlbums()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Albums::className(), ['Album_id' => 'Album_id'])->viaTable('photo_album', ['photo_id' => 'photo_id']);
}
```

То можно вытащить из "общей" таблицы массив Id'шников альбомов с соответсвующим ему текущим id фото с помощью связи photoAlbums и засунуть их в атрибут $model->albums.

```
function getCheckedAlbumsIds($model)
{
    foreach($model->photoAlbums as $cat) //photoAlbums - там хранятся все id'шники альбомов соответствующие текущей фотографии  
    {
        $a[] = $cat->album_id;
    }
    return $a;
}
$model->album_id = getCheckedAlbumsIds($model);
```

И затем:

```
$form->field($model, 'albums')->checkboxList( PhotoAlbums::find()->select('name', 'album_id')->indexBy('id')->column() )
```

Comment: Очень интересный стиль наименования полей в габлицах БД)

Comment: Хорошо. Как вывести список отмеченных чекбоксов я понял. А вот как теперь сохранить теперь это состояние?

Comment: Я так полагаю, придется накостылять. Или писать метод, который принимает IDшники всех альбомов и самостоятельно создает необходимые связи. Либо все это дело реализовывать в контроллере, что не есть хорошо. Либо писать еще одну модель, которая будет всем этим заниматься. Что тоже не очень хорошо...